# Extension of Fourier transform to $L^2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

We defined the fourier transform and it's inversion for the Schwartz class $S(\mathbb{R})$. Since $S(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, we can find for a given $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ a sequence $f_n \in S(\mathbb{R})$, s.t. $f_n$ converges to $f$ in the $L^2$-sense. Using Plancherel's identity for $S(\mathbb{R})$, we can also easy show that $\hat f_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, where $\hat f_n$ is the fourier transform of $f_n$. Since $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is complete $\hat f_n$ converges, say to the limit $\hat g$. This $\hat g$ is per definition the fourier transform of $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Now, I find in the literature often the statement that the fourier transform of $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ is also given by $\hat f(\xi)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-n}^{n}f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$-sense. In the proof they always define $f_n(x)=f(x)\chi_{[-n,n]}$ and show that $f_n$ converges to $f$ in the $L^2$-sense. My question: These $f_n(x)=f(x)\chi_{[-n,n]}$ need not to be in $S(\mathbb{R})$, so the framework from above might not work!? I know that these $f_n\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$, but $S(\mathbb{R}) \subset L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the Parseval (Plancherel) identity for Schwartz class, then the Fourier transform extends to $L^2$ as you noted in the first paragraph. For $f\in L^2\cap L^1$, it's not hard to show that this continuous extension to $L^2$ is the same as the classical integral definition:
$$
                 \hat{f}(s)=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-R}^{R}f(x)e^{-isx}dx,\;\;\; f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})\cap L^2(\mathbb{R}).
$$
The convergence of the above limit is pointwise everywhere, and it converges in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ as well.

Alternatively, can start with the above classical definition of the Fourier transform as a pointwise limit, show that the Parseval identity holds, and use this to show that the above limit converges to $\hat{f}$ for any $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ because $\chi_{[-R,R]}f \in L^1\cap L^2$ for any finite $R$, which gives the Parseval identity for $\chi_{[-R,R]}f$.

Comment: But if $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})\setminus  L^1(\mathbb{R})$ the "truncation"-definition doesn't hold?

Comment: @RandomUser : If $f \in L^2$, then $\chi_{[-R,R]}f \in L^2\cap L^1$.

Comment: Thank you! So the "truncation"-definition holds for all $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Why do I need the "abstract" definition for $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ with the sequence $f_n\in S(\mathbb{R})$ at all?

Comment: @RandomUser : I've always been a bit confused about that, too. :) And, actually, the classical definition agrees with the spectral theory way of dealing with the transform as well. Schwartz space makes some of the proofs easier because of having smoothness, and I think that's the reason people take that approach. What's nice about the classical approach is that you can carry it out in the context of Riemann integration, which gives you a larger audience; but the approach works for the Lebesgue integral as well.