# a few questions about $L_2$ and Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

I need to proove or refute these claims.

1. if $f ∈ L_2[-π,π]$ is integrable then $f$ is Piecewise Continuous
2. Fourier transform is well defined for every $f ∈ L_2[-π,π]$
3. if $f:R\rightarrow F$ is Piecewise smooth on $R$ then  $f ∈ L_1[R]$

I think 1 is true but I don't know how to show that.
about the rest I am just not sure :(
Any help will be great

Comment: We need to expand to Plancherel transform to do Fourier transform on L2 functions. Usually it is only defined on Schwarz class of infinitely continously differentiable functions of limited support . https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1840207/extension-of-fourier-transform-to-l2-mathbbr

Answer (score 0):

1. No.  Neither Riemann integrable nor Lebesgue integrable functions need to be piecewise continuous.  See the [Thomae function.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function)

---

2. Yes. $L_2[-\pi,\pi] \subset L_1[-\pi,\pi]$, and the Fourier transform is defined for any element of $L_1$.  (Note: $L_2(\mathbb R) \not\subset L_1(\mathbb R)$, so this argument does not work there.  As mathreader said, the *Plancherel transform* extends the Fourier transform to $L_2(\mathbb R)$.)

Proof for $L_2[-\pi,\pi] \subset L_1[-\pi,\pi]$.  Let $f \in L_2[-\pi,\pi]$.
Note $|f(x)| \le |f(x)|^2 + 1$, which we can see by considering the two cases $|f(x)|\le 1$ and $|f(x)| > 1$.  So
$$
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f(x)|\;dx \le \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f(x)|^2\;dx + 2\pi
< +\infty
$$
and $f \in L_1[-\pi,\pi]$

---

3. No. $f(x) = 2+\sin x$ is smooth on $\mathbb R$, but $f$ is not in $L_1(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: thank you!
about 3 I managed to get that just after I posted the question..XD
about 1, do you have specific example?
about 2. how do I show L2[−π,π]⊂L1[−π,π]?
thank you for your help!!!

Comment: yea got it
thank you both
I also found another example for 1
f(x) = x^(-0.5)